# I am trying to find a way to open this lock to replace battery

Tags: lock

I am trying to find a way to open this lock to replace batteries.  I find no way to open it.  See front and back pictures attached.

[image: Front of Lock]

[image: Back of Lock]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No gurantee, but see those little holes around the collar on the back handle? You can see two of them in your photo. Those often either (a) give a tool a grip to unlock & unthread the collar, allowing you access to full disassembly or (b) require insertion of a tool to release a spring that keeps the collar in place. that would be my starting point.

Comment: I found the manufacturer part #  LINEAR CORPORATION | 212LS-C26DCR-RT | 212LS. And was able to look at the manual and it does say to thread the collar to complete the install of the face plate.  So you are correct JBH!  Have not tried it yet.

Comment: I was able to unscrew the collar and replace the batteries.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad I could help.